# What is the right way to store datasets for a CNN project

Tags: dataset, version-control

Our image classification project has thousands of raw photos, masks and reshaped images. We store source code in git. But datasets don't belong to source code version control. How should we store thee sets of images?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use google drive to save these and import the drive on your code.